# .Net Frame Core Application with multiple users and central DB

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, rbac

We have a task to design a software using entity frame core and a Central SQL DB. The software will have multiple users with RBAC(Role Based Access Control). DB design shall implement user group table and users with many to many relationship.

I've read about RBAC and RLS (Row Level Security) in SQL but I can't link it to code. It will take alot of effort to create secured layer in the Database but I don't know how to use this in the code. I mean putting effort in the database design tables will be implemented in the code using the poco-class but putting all this effort in data security will affect the performance and will make the software very dependent on the the database

1- How can I implement RBAC in the code?
2- Where to start searching?
3- Should I just but my restrictions in the code using the queries and GUI?
4- Should I depend on the DBMS to manage my security or use it just as a backup layer?
5- What is the best practice or design pattern for the application and the Database? Should I map users in the database with RBAC and RLS and then just using them to sign in the application?

Comment: *Database* security has little if anything to do with *application* security. RBAC is baked into .NET and ASP.NET going back to 2002. It's still there in .NET Core and has nothing to do with *database* security.

Comment: Forums for example have lots of roles, guests, editors, users, moderators, administrators. Those are typically entries in a table. The code uses those roles to decide what *pages* a user is allowed to see, what the menu looks like and, should a user get clever, whether to reject a direct GET to `admin.php` for example. The application does that by loading the user's profile and checking the roles and permissions on each request

Comment: For ASP.NET Core, check the [Authorization section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-3.1), especially the [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.1) section

Answer (score 0):

> How can I implement RBAC in the code?

We published [GitHub examples](https://www.devexpress.com/go/XAF_Security_NonXAF_Console_EFCore.aspx) illustrating how to access data protected by the DevExpress XAF [Security System](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113366/concepts/security-system) for Entity Framework Core 3 (CTP).

For more information, please review [Frequently Asked Questions](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t886740/faq-xaf-user-authentication-and-group-authorization-api-for-devexpress-xpo-and-microsoft) and this [feature and architecture overview](https://www.devexpress.com/go/XAF_Security_NonXAF_Series.aspx). In FAQ, we also briefly compared this API to the standard ASP.NET Core features - I hope this answers your questions.

Disclaimer: this is a third-party commercial product with a free trial.